# how to derive the canonical form of a transfer second order equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, control-theory, derived-functors

How to derive the canonical form of the second order transfer function??

$$\frac{(\omega_n)^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns + (\omega_n)^2}$$

Comment: Isn't it already in canonical form?

Comment: This follows directly from the relevant differential equation.

Comment: The question is how this form is derived. 
I would think it's derived from some standard physical system, but how?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical example for this is the spring and damper system you can read about [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping). If a mass $m$ is attached to an ideal, massless, perfrectly elastic spring and displaced by a length $x$, the force on the spring is $-kx$ where $k$ is a constant. Thus, applying Newton's second law, we find:

$$m\ddot{x} = -kx$$

Now imagine a dissipative term proportional to the velocity $-\gamma \dot{x}$. This is essentially like including a viscous damper on the spring so the overall equation is

$$m\ddot{x} + \gamma\dot{x} + kx = 0,$$

Which is the correct form for the characteristic equation. Now we need to get the coefficients right:

Recall that $s = j\omega$ so the dimensions of $s$ are Hz. We can introduce the natural frequency as the parameter for which $\ddot{x} = -\omega_n^2x$, and a dimensionless number $\zeta$ for which $\gamma = \omega_n\zeta$ so that the units of the terms all match and the dissipative term can be analyzed as a ratio of the damping coefficient to the natural frequency. Since any transfer function is trivial for the free response (by definition) we simply need to add a coefficient for the forcing term, which is typically $K$ but also often written as $\omega^2_n$ so that oscillations about the natural frequency are rejected in the closed loop by default. The latter form in particular is a bit nicer because it's clear the overall TF is dimensionless and no ambiguous gain, which might be interpreted to be from some $P$-controller, etc. is accidentally inferred.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function you've posted has this form 
$$
G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{ b_0 s^2 + b_1 s + b_2 }{ s^2 + a_1 s + a_2 }
$$

[Controllable canonical](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html) form can be utilized to represents the system as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-a_2 & -a_1
\end{bmatrix}  \\
y&=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_2-a_2b_0 & b_1-a_1b_0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

where $b_0=0,b_1=0,b_2= \omega^2_n ,a_1=2\zeta \omega_n,a_2=\omega^2_n $. The state space representation of the system is

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-\omega^2_n & -2\zeta \omega_n
\end{bmatrix} \\
y&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega^2_n & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The question is not referring to 'canonical form' in the sense of CCF or OCF, though I admit I was confused too on a second look.